# Promotional Mathematica button

Tags: discussion

Is there a nice official "Download Mathematica Free Trial" HTML button (or something similar) to encourage people to try Mathematica, that we can put on our web sites?

Comment: I did not really know how to tag this question, feel free to retag it

Comment: magma, I don't think this question is appropriate for the site.  I'm going to move it to Meta, even though I don't think it fits there either, just to give it a chance.  IMHO this kind of question would be better asked in [chat]

Comment: Ok, I realize it is different from mainstream questions

Comment: Re: promotion, there's this bunch: http://www.wolframcdn.com/sponsor-ads/Mathematica-ring-a.png
http://www.wolframcdn.com/sponsor-ads/calculator.png
http://www.wolframcdn.com/sponsor-ads/cant-take-it.png
http://www.wolframcdn.com/sponsor-ads/fall-in-love.png
http://www.wolframcdn.com/sponsor-ads/einstein.png